# How to update and save a python script (variables only, no logic) based on user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, user-input, overwrite

I have a script, and another Python file `mappings.py` that contains a bunch of `dicts` and `tuples-of-tuples`). Each of these has been populated on Day 0 with a baseline of mappings of let's pairs of Name and Age values. These, in turn, have been added as rows of a reference spreadsheet.

On any given day, data will be read from a new day's spreadsheet. If any of the records is already in one of the mappings dicts or tuples, the data will be written to the appropriate row.

Here's the challenge: On any given day, if a row in the input spreadsheet *does not yet have a entry* in `mappings.py`, I want to:

- Prompt the user to specify a value of Age for the given Name
- Somehow add this Name:Age pair to the appropriate dict or tuple in mappings.py, such that on subsequent days, if the script encounters that Name again, it already "knows" about it.

So the question is: how do I append to a given data structure in a file, not in memory, but in the actual file itself? So if the dict in question is called `mydict`, and I have a new Name:Age pair to add, I can do, in memory:

```
mappings.py.mydict[$newName] = [$newAge]
```

But how do I actually update the file in place, for saving, with this new data? The end user won't want to open `mappings.py` directly, so I will be showing some pop-up to receive the pair as specified by the user. It's then the saving of this pair that I am wondering how best to do.

Comment: You should store the data in a separate data file, not in the source code itself.

Comment: Separate to the need to be able to add pairs, the file needs to be able to look up values of specific keys in specific dicts, hence having the values in a python file rather than plain text.

Comment: Nope, still not necessary. There are a variety of ways to store complex objects in data files separate from the program itself, including JSON, pickling, and even plain text.

Comment: With a (admittedly hurried) quick playing around with both JSON and pickle, I found that both *overwrote* the pickled /json'ed data (structures) completely, and I was unable to *append* to data structures (which is what I need).

Comment: BTW, it would be better to store the date of birth (or at least the year of birth) rather than the age, otherwise your data will become invalid over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to use pickle (or cPickle in Python 2, since it's much faster than plain pickle) is to

1. unpickle your data structures from the pickle file
2. update the data structures in your program
3. pickle the updated structures, over-writing the original pickle file, possibly saving a back-up of that original file.

The pickling process is reasonably fast, so unless you're pickling many millions of (name, age) pairs that strategy should be adequate.

It's not practical to append data to individual items in a pickle file. It's *possible* to append items in a pickle file if you use the human-readable pickle protocol version 0, but it's messy and manually modifying the contents of a pickle file is *not* a good strategy.

However, it's quite easy to append new data structures to an existing pickle file, you just have to handle the data appropriately when you unpickle the file.

The code below reads a series of dicts from a pickle file, merging them all into a single dict. It then creates a new dict and appends it to the existing pickle file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Appending data to a pickle file

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31365239/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.07.12
'''

import cPickle as pickle
from random import choice, randint
from string import ascii_lowercase

#Create a random lowercase string
def rand_str(strlen=5):
    return ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in xrange(strlen)])

#Name of pickle file
fname = 'pickletest.pkl'

#Attempt to read the dicts from the pickle file
all_data = {}
count = 0
try:
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
        while True:
            d = pickle.load(fh)
            count += 1
            print 'Record %2d: %s' % (count, d)
            all_data.update(d)
except EOFError:
    pass
except IOError as e:
    print '%s; the file will be created.' % e

print '\nCurrent data\n%s' % all_data

#Create a new record
d = dict((rand_str(), randint(10, 99)) for _ in xrange(5))
print '\nNew data\n%s' % d

#Append the record to the pickle file, using protocol 2
with open(fname, 'ab') as fh:
    pickle.dump(d, fh, 2)
```

Here's some typical output for 3 runs of the program.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pickletest.pkl'; the file will be created.

Current data
{}

New data
{'veria': 65, 'glsjp': 69, 'zvvho': 11, 'ejqnt': 36, 'gmpaq': 54}

#----------------------------------------------------------------

Record  1: {'veria': 65, 'glsjp': 69, 'zvvho': 11, 'ejqnt': 36, 'gmpaq': 54}

Current data
{'veria': 65, 'glsjp': 69, 'zvvho': 11, 'ejqnt': 36, 'gmpaq': 54}

New data
{'dptdp': 31, 'waydc': 81, 'zejbe': 34, 'fimgy': 51, 'sdwnp': 90}

#----------------------------------------------------------------

Record  1: {'veria': 65, 'glsjp': 69, 'zvvho': 11, 'ejqnt': 36, 'gmpaq': 54}
Record  2: {'dptdp': 31, 'sdwnp': 90, 'zejbe': 34, 'fimgy': 51, 'waydc': 81}

Current data
{'fimgy': 51, 'zejbe': 34, 'ejqnt': 36, 'gmpaq': 54, 'veria': 65, 'glsjp': 69, 'waydc': 81, 'dptdp': 31, 'zvvho': 11, 'sdwnp': 90}

New data
{'cavsw': 84, 'unokw': 14, 'irqfh': 60, 'avddt': 50, 'pszdk': 40}
```

---

In your question you mention that you have several dicts and tuples of tuples that you need to save. It would be possible to adapt my code to handle that, but if you have lots of separate dicts & tuples it may get messy.

It may be worthwhile to convert those tuples of tuples to dicts, since it's *much* faster to search a `dict` than a tuple or list. Also consider combining your dicts. If it's not appropriate to throw everything into a single flat dict, consider using a list of dicts or a dict of dicts.

Answer (score 1):

If the mappings.py doesn't need to be readable by the user, use a regular dict and -load\save it as a `pickle` (see relevant issue)

Comment: Can pickle append to objects (data structures) as well as overwrite them? If I pickle.load() the pickled data containing various `dicts` and `tuples-of-tuples`, is it possible to append to one of these variables, or must the whole data structure be overwritten?

Comment: They can be interacted with as regular objects. Their entire purpose is to allow you to save data for later use for whatever processing you need to do.

Comment: After you load the `pickle` you have yours original data-structure _in_ _memory_. After your adding & changes - save it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a structure of dicts, lists, strings and numbers that can be updated dynamically, it seems you're describing a document oriented database, like mongodb. Although, if you have the option of just loading a normal file, changing what you need and overwriting it, then that would be much more simple.

Personally I would go with json over pickle, since you only mention types that are json serializable. Advantages include the file being readable by humans and other (non-Python) software, as well as no problems with compatibility of Pickle versions. Downside would be that you can't store e.g. a function or class.